# How to check statistical significance when comparing four different datasets with same sample size and classes tested on same object detection model

Tags: statistical-significance, object-detection

I have results of testing four different image datasets that are identical in all aspects sample size number of classes, number of images for each class etc. except they were captured using different methods. They are tested on the same object detection model and I have the Precision, Recall and F1 scores of the tests.
The goal is to determine if using one method to capture images is superior to the other, in a statistically significant way, using proper statistical analysis.

I don't have access to the datasets or the model, so I can't do any additional investigation to gain more information, I just have the Precision, Recall and F1 scores at my disposal.

Can it be done? If so, what is the most appropriate statistical analysis to accomplish this?

I appreciate all help in advance